# Wordpress multiple edit screen

Tags: php, wordpress, function, edit

I was wondering if there is a way to bypass the "view posts" screen (for a custom post type), and simply have an edit screen that displays all fields and you can edit them all at once and simple click save. So instead of viewing them all, and clicking edit on each one, you just edit them all at once, there is no "view page" or "edit individual" page.

If I have to use a plugin I will, but i'd rather go through functions.php, I just don't really know where to start because I haven't used Wordpress a lot.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In register_post_type() set the option show_ui to false. This will prevent wordpress from showing the custom edit screens. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
Then, use add_menu_page() to create your custom admin page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page
Generally speaking, everything is possible through functions.php

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't know about the show_ui - then I'm assuming I have to write a function to display all the entries, then loop through them and save each one when the save button is clicked?